# Conditional expectation of the exponential of the integral of a diffusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be the unique strong solution of the SDE, and let $c\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$
dX_t=\mathbb{1}_{\{X_t>c\}}dt+\sigma dB_t \quad \text{with} \quad X_0=x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Define process $A_t=\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{\{X_u>c\}}du$ for all $t\geq 0$ for some bounded deterministic function $g$.

Suppose for any $t\geq 0$, $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{A_t}\right]=f(t,x)$ for some known function $f$.

Then is it true that: for any $0\leq t\leq s<\infty$,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{A_s-A_t}|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=f(s-t,X_t)?
$$

Comment: Simplifying the system to the bone by setting $\sigma=0$ and $g=f$ makes it a deterministic ODE problem. Would you then think hat $\int_s^tg(X_u)du=\int_0^{s-t}g(X_u)du$ ?

Comment: Thank you! I have noticed the problem and have edited the question.

Comment: Looks better. If you write $A_s-A_t$ as $\int_t^s1_{\{X_u>c\}}\,du=\int_0^{s-t}1_{\{X_{t+u}>c\}}\,du$ the result should follow from the Markov property of $X_t$.